# Git Rebase is not rebasing the entire branch

Tags: git, git-rebase

For some reason, running a `git rebase` is suddenly not rebasing my entire branch and I cannot imagine why. What I have before rebase is the following:

[image]

What I have after running `git rebase develop` is this:

[image]

Notice that none of the commits from the branch came along in the rebase. At this point I have to run a `git reset --hard` on the last commit of what is now a headless branch to get things back in order.

Strangely enough, if I create additional commits on the `feature-relationalSurveys` branch beyond those shown in the screenshot and then rebase, all additional commits will come along in the rebase. It's like git doesn't know where the branch actually starts. I've never seen this happen before and I have no idea what's causing it or how to fix it. Any ideas?

Comment: Could you show `develop` prior to the rebase please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to take a guess based on the information provided.  Either A) your visualization tool is broken or B) `develop` already contained all the content of `feature-relationalSurveys`.  You can test A by trying another visualization tool like `git log --decorate --graph`.

Lemme explain B.  The key pieces of information are...

- `feature-relationalSurveys` is at a merge point, rebase should not merge.
- `feature-relationalSurveys` is at the same point as `develop`.

  - Even more strange, it's at the same point as `origin/develop`.
- None of the commits in `feature-relationalSurveys` are at its tip after the rebase.

  - I presume those commits are deeper in the history.

The only way I can think this happened is if you had something like this...

```
2 [develop]
|
1
|  A' [feature-relationalSurveys]
A  |
|  B'
B  |
|  C'
C /
|/
D
```

I'm not exactly sure how you'd get into that state, maybe through a weird merge or rebase, but there you go.  When Git goes to rebase `feature-relationalSurveys` onto develop it notices `C'`'s content is the same as `C`, so it skips it.  `B'`'s content is the same as `B`, so it skips it.  `A'` and `A` are the same, skipped.  There's no differing content left, so it just plops `feature-relationalSurveys` where `develop` is.

```
2 [develop] [feature-relationalSurveys]
|
1
|
A
|
B
|
C
|
D
```

None of `feature-relationalSurveys` changes are visible at the tip of `develop` because they're buried earlier in `develop`'s history.

That's my best guess, and one only you can verify.  It would help to show the state of `develop` prior to the rebase.

Comment: You nailed it with B, totally my own lack of attention. I'm guessing that I didn't switch to develop when creating a 2nd feature branch; instead I branched off of an existing feature branch that I wasn't ready to merge in. When I rebased the 2nd feature branch onto develop the commits from the 1st came along for the ride and subsequently got merged in. Then when trying to rebase the 1st feature branch onto develop, if no new commits have been made, there's nothing to rebase because the 2nd branch based on the 1st already did the work. Dumb move on my part, thanks for pointing it out.